# How to store future time in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm developing a tennis matchmaking app where you can post a match and decide at what time and day the match is. I cannot figure out the best way to store time and date in mongodb. I want to be able to display time, use it for search queries and display in text form like "the match is in 1 hour" any suggestion? I was thinking to use moment but I still haven't figured out how.

Comment: MongoDB will accept any time in proper date format.

Comment: Sure but i wanted to know if there was a good way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would store the date in the default [ISODate](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) format supported by mongoDB. It will have the date and the time on it. Once you have the records then you can query against them with `$gt` and `$lt` operators etc.

On the UI side you can use `momentjs` (or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) etc) to consume those dates and get the `1 hour from now` etc. moment actually has build in [humanize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) methods for that where date-fns has various [distanceInWords](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/distanceInWords) etc methods.